# AvalonEdit debug messages: How do I turn them off?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, avalonedit

I've got AvalonEdit embedded in a WPF application. As I resize, change text, etc, it continually sends debug messages to the console output window. Messages like:

```
OnHighlightStateChanged forces redraw of line 13    
Building line 13
```

Is there any way to turn these off? There are lots of them and they bury my other debug messages.
Thanks.
(I'm on Visual Studio 2013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a debug build of AvalonEdit?
You shouldn't see these if you use a release build / the official binaries (for example, from the NuGet package).

If for some reason you need to use self-compiled debug binaries of AvalonEdit, the answer is simple: remove the `Debug.WriteLine()` calls from the AvalonEdit source code.

Comment: Thanks, that works. As you said, the release build doesn't have it. Somehow I was still using a debug version.